# What is the command that can execute lazy load of image in HTL code AEM 6.5?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, sightly, aem-6

I have to implement a javascript to the components for the lazy load of images in a site in AEM 6.5. How do I change.

I have created dailog for component and implemented javascript in clintlibs in AEM 6.5. What do I change in HTL code for the lazyload of image ?.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [AEM Core WCM Components](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components) already have support for lazy loading of images:

- for `Image (v3)` using native browser capabilities, example [markup](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/main/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v3/image/image.html#L36)

```
<img ... loading="${image.lazyEnabled ? 'lazy' : ''}" ...
```

- for `Image (v2)` through JavaScript, example [markup](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/main/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v2/image/image.html#L21-L22) and [JS code](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/main/content/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core/wcm/components/image/v2/image/clientlibs/site/js/image.js#L371-L379)

```
<div ...
    data-cmp-lazy="${image.lazyEnabled}"
    data-cmp-lazythreshold="${image.lazyThreshold}"
    ...
```

```
update = function() {
    if (that._properties.lazy) {
        if (isLazyVisible()) {
           loadImage();
        }
    } else {
        loadImage();
    }
};
```